# Numbers of the kind $0.aaa\ldots =\frac{1}{aaa\ldots a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, rational-numbers, decimal-expansion

What are the integers $a$ such that
$$
0.\underbrace{aaa\ldots}_{\infty\text{ times}} =\frac{1}{\underbrace{aaa\ldots}_{k\text{ times}}}
$$

eg.
$$
0.333\ldots=1/3\\
$$
while
$$
0.1616\ldots\ne1/16\ne1/1616\ne1/\underbrace{161616\ldots}_{\text{any }k}
$$

---

I was able to reduce $a$ to
$$
a=\frac{10^d-1}{\sqrt{10^{k\,d}-1}}
$$
where
$d$ is the number of digits in $a$ in base $10$. If this is correct, is $k=1,d=1$ the only solution for integral $a$?

Comment: @player3236 Careful: $a$ is not assumed to be a single digit.

Comment: For base $10$, $10^{kd}-1$ is a square only for $kd = 1$ since $10^{kd} - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ otherwise. Hence $a$ is *rational* only for $k=d=1$.

Comment: @player3236 That's a complete answer; I think you should write that up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think a *complete* answer should cover all bases (no pun intended). We will have:

$$a = \frac {b^d-1}{\sqrt{b^{kd}-1}}$$

for any base $b$. However for $k\ge 2$:

$$\sqrt{b^{kd}-1}\ge \sqrt{b^{2d}-1} = \sqrt{(b^d-1)(b^d+1)} \ge b^d-1$$

forcing $a<1$. Hence we must have $k=1$, with $a = \sqrt{b^d-1}$, or $b^d - a^2 = 1$.

By Catalan's conjecture (or Mihăilescu's theorem, or if you are interested, this $1+a^2 = b^d$ is a special case proven by V. A. Lebesgue using Gaussian integers), if $d \ge 2$ there are no solutions. This forces $d = 1$, and we have only the uninteresting case:

$$1+a^2 = b$$

so our choice of $b$ must be one more than some square. For base $10$, $10 = 1+3^2$, so $0.\dot3 = \dfrac13$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ have $d$ digits in base $b$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
a\ge b^{d-1}=1{\underbrace{00..0}_{d-1\text{ times}}}{}_{b}\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$
\begin{align}
\underbrace{aaa\ldots a}_{k\text{ times}}&\ge1000\ldots0100\ldots0100\ldots0_b\\
&>1000\ldots0000\ldots0000\ldots0_b\\
&=b^{k\, d -1}
\end{align}
$$
So
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{aaa\ldots a}&<b^{1-k\,d}\\
\end{align}
$$
If $k\,d>1$,then
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{aaa\ldots a}&<b^{-(k\,d-1)}\\
&=0.\underbrace{000\ldots 0}_{k\,d-2\text{ times}}1\\
\therefore 0.aaa\ldots&<0.000\ldots 01\\
\therefore 0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_d a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_d \ldots&<0.000\ldots 01\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
where $a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_d$ is written showing its digits in base $b$. If $k\,d>2$, there is a non-zero number of $0$s after the decimal in the RHS of eqn. $1$ implying $a_1=0$. If $k\,d=2$, then the LHS $<0.1$ which again implies $a_1=0$. In either case, this contradicts the assumption that $a$ has $d$ digits in base $b$. Therefore, for postive integral $k,d$
$$
k\,d=1\implies k =1,d=1
$$
So the required numbers are of the form
$$
\begin{align}
0.a_1a_1a_1\ldots&=\frac{1}{a_1}\\
a_1.a_1...&=b/a_1\\
a_1+\frac{1}{a_1}&=\frac{b}{a_1}\\
a_1&=+ \sqrt{b-1}=a
\end{align}
$$

same as @player3236's result above. For e.g. $0.\bar{2}_5=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_{5}$. Note that $b>2$ since $a=0,1$ don't satisfy the condition in the question.